# Migrating the Rating for our discussion board list from on-premises to online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, pnp-powershell

I have a team site inside our sharepoint farm 2013. and the team site contain a Discussion board list which have rating enabled. now using a third party tool named share-gate i migrated the team site to a classic online team site, where everything have been migrated correctly, except the rating for the discussion board list items. so the migrated discussion board list will have the discussion board items and their replies migrated well, but the number of likes will be = 0.
i contacted the third party company and they mentioned that currently migrating the rating is not available. but in our case i need the rating info,because we use the rating as a formal way to confirm that someone read the discussion board list.

**so my question,what are the approaches to migrate the rating in my case?** for example can I write a power-shell script which read the rating for the discussion board list items and update the migrated items? both environments (on-premises & on-line ) are based on the same Active directory.
Thanks